# Angular - Populating form with Model - Type Number not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im creating an edit view that should fill with the data from `ng-init="findOne().`

It seems to get everything except the price input which is the only number input form.

Is there anything special about the `type="number"` that it wont use the `model="saving.price"` yet for example it will fill the `model="saving.retailer"` box which is `type="text"`.

Heres the View Code

```
        <!-- Retailer Box Start-->

          <div class="form-group new-deal-form"
               ng-class="{ 'has-error' : createSavingForm.title.$invalid && submitted}" show-errors>
            <label for="retailer">Retailer</label>
            <input name="retailer" type="text" ng-model="saving.retailer" id="retailer" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Retailer" required>
            <div class="sub-label">Enter the Retailer of the Deal.</div>
            <div ng-messages="savingForm.savingsCTRL.retailer.$error" role="alert">
              <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Retailer is required.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Retailer Box End-->

          <!-- Price Box Start-->

          <div class="form-group new-deal-form"
               ng-class="{ 'has-error' : createSavingForm.title.$invalid && submitted}" show-errors>
            <label for="price">Price(Euro)</label>
            <input name="price" type="number" ng-model="price" id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"
                   required>
            <div class="sub-label">Enter the Price of the Deal. 0 for no price.</div>
            <div ng-messages="savingForm.savingsCTRL.price.$error" role="alert">
              <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Price is required.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Price Box End-->
```

Batarang clearly shows the model as having the price. If i enter something in the price box and hit update, it saves the new price.

Comment: Not clear what issue is. Note that types other than "text" will be undefined in model until they are valid per that type .... regardless of what is entered. Same if you use `pattern`

Comment: what do you mean by valid per that type? The JSON data is definitely an actual number is thats what you mean. Edit - I notice that if i change it to type="text" it works and puts "200" in the box but that lets them put letters in the box when updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your model but there is something special about `<input type="number">` - it can only be binded to a number (`price = 2`), not a string whose value is a number (`price = '2'`).

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.priceStr = '2';
  $scope.priceNum = 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>string model </label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="priceStr" /><br/>
    <label>number model </label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="priceNum" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok. I just noticed that in the model its price="200". I suppose thats the problem. Yeah just checked the model and its a String. My mistake.